# Centos 7, HA postgresql12, patroni with etcd v3.4

Tags: centos7, high-availability, etcd, patroni

I followed this document but dont know how to enable v2 so that patroni can work with, can anyone help?
https://computingforgeeks.com/setup-etcd-cluster-on-centos-debian-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting `etcd` v3.4, [etcd wouldn't serve API v2 by default](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.4/upgrades/upgrade_3_4/#make-etcd---enable-v2false-default). You'll need to add `--enable-v2=true` in your `etcd` startup script to enable API v2.

In your guide's case, add it on step 3 in `ExecStart` when creating your `etcd.service` systemd unit file, i.e.

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \\
  --name ${ETCD_NAME} \\
  --enable-v2=true \\
  --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd \\
  ...
```